# SQL: Using Textbox value in "LIKE" query condition

Tags: sql, ms-access

SQL: So, I'm trying to make a query with a condition comparing "Row" values with a value of textbox placed in a form (using MS Access '10) with use of wildcards, and this line which is propably wrong in **bold part**, but I got little idea what to do:

SELECT Table.*
FROM Table
WHERE (((Table.Row) **Like '%"[Forms]![SomeForm]![Texbox1]"%'));**

Ideas?

Somehow WHERE **(((Table.Row)=[Forms]![SomeForm]![Textbox1]));** works as a search for full string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE Table.Row ALike '%' & [Forms]![SomeForm]![Texbox1] & '%'
```

In ANSI 89 mode ...

```
WHERE Table.Row Like '*' & [Forms]![SomeForm]![Texbox1] & '*'
```

In ANSI 92 mode ...

```
WHERE Table.Row Like '%' & [Forms]![SomeForm]![Texbox1] & '%'
```

Or you could use `InStr()` instead of a `Like` comparison.

```
WHERE InStr(1, Table.Row, [Forms]![SomeForm]![Texbox1]) > 0
```

Comment: Replacing % with * doesn't work, but HansUp way does. Thanks a lot! I'm somehow suprised with "ALike" expression.

Comment: `ALike` is not widely known, but can be useful since you don't need to be concerned whether the query runs under ANSI 89 or 92 mode.  `ALike`  always expects wild cards as % and _ (instead of \* and ?).

Comment: Ah, wasn't really what you were doing with those quotes.

Answer (score 1):

In Access, use * instead of % for wildcard

Comment: And use + instead of &